# How to update nested store in MobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I've got an App that is wrapped with a Provider.
Deeper in the App, I'm using a component that's usually is stand alone and has its own Provider. 
When the "Master" store gets updated, I'd like to pass on the information to the internal store. 
When I'm doing so, I'm getting a warning from mobx saying - 
`Mobx Provider: Provider store 'internalStore' has changed. Please avoid replacing stores as the change might not propagate to all children`.

I can think of two solutions - 
 1. Store the store (internalStore) in the RootStore (pun intended)
 2. Add an update method to the internalStore

#### App

`const App = (props) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        App...
      </Provider>
    )
}`

#### Internal component -

`const Internal = (props) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={internalStore}>
        <ReusedCompoenent />
      </Provider>
    )
}`

What do you think? Ideas?

Comment: If you want to update your `internalStore` when something in the `rootStore` changes, couldn't you instead put both stores in the top-most provider and use a computed value in the `internalStore` derived from values in the `rootStore`?

Comment: In the mobx docs, there is a point about combining stores that might help you: https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html#combining-multiple-stores

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

Think of internal stores as a loose store somehwere referenced. Props on this store are observable and each observable is tracked globally. Thus every time you add a store there are more observable being tracked globally. This in itself is only a memory problem. The render problem is that this new Store it's observables are not linked to the already existing react components. thus the existing react components wont trigger to re-render. You would have to forcefully drop and recreate all these components to get rid of all the wrong listeners.

However if you want to use mobx state in components i'd advise you to use the following method: https://alexhisen.gitbooks.io/mobx-recipes/content/use-observables-instead-of-state-in-react-components.html

Other than that try to keep all your stores singletons. maybe this would already solve your problem (as long as the store is not re-created, eg: by HMR or anything like this you should be fine).